# How can I redirect a long key press to a device file in bash?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I need a long key press to be redirected to a device file. If I send the same key multiple times, it is considered as separate key inputs (with carrige return). I just need one long key press. How can I achieve this?
Thank you. Any help appreciated!

Edit: I just meant the normal redirection operator in bash which is > or >>(append). I need a long key press to be simulated to a device file.I am just using bash for the envionment.
For example: If I need to input a key to the device file, I can give a bash command

echo "s" > /dev/device

Comment: what do you mean by "redirected to a device file"? what application / user interface are you using? could you give an example? is your Q about distinguishing long key presses in an xkb config? (I don't think that's possible, but I may be wrong). Please add all the details to your Q.

Comment: Your example `s > /dev/` gives the error `/dev/: is a directory`.  I'd also expect to see the error `s: command not found` (unless `s` is a script you've also written).  Please include an actual command that demonstrates the problem you're seeing.  You say that you want to redirect a *long* key press, implying that you've got this working for shorter presses -- what's the command that works for you for short presses, and in what way are the results different to what you expect when you hold the key for longer?